# Read multiple files with fileinput at a certain line

Tags: python, file-io

I have multiple files which I need to open and read (I thought may it will be easier with fileinput.input()). Those files contain at the very beginning non-relevant information, what I need is all the information below this specific line **ID[tab]NAME[tab]GEO[tab]FEATURE** (some times from line 32, but unfortunately some times at any other line), then I want to store them in a list ("entries")

```
ID[tab]NAME[tab]GEO[tab]FEATURE
1   aa      us      A1
2   bb      ko      B1
3   cc      ve      C1
.
.
.
```

Now, before reading from line 32 (see code below), I will like to read from the above line. Is it possible to do this with fileinput? or am I going the wrong way. Is there another mor simple way to do this? Here is my code until now:

```
entries = list()

for line in fileinput.input():
    if fileinput.filelineno() > 32:
        entries.append(line.strip().split("\t"))
```

I'm trying to implement this idea with Python 3.2

## UPDATE:

Here is how my code looks now, but still out of range. I need to add some of the entries to a dictionary. Am I missing something?

```
filelist = fileinput.input()

entries = []

for fn in filelist:
    for line in fn:
        if line.strip() == "ID\tNAME\tGEO\tFEATURE":
            break
    entries.extend(line.strip().split("\t")for line in fn)

dic = collections.defaultdict(set)

for e in entries:
    dic[e[1]].add(e[3])
```

Error:

```
dic[e[1]].add(e[3])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: look into file pointers but i dont think it is possible the way it is explained at least.

Comment: @jgr208, thanks for your comment. What I want to do, is just to read from this line: ID[tab]NAME[tab]GEO[tab]FEATURE. I read the whole file, find this line and start reading the document from this part on

Comment: oh well yea just have the file pointer stop at that line when that part is found and then continue

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the file looking for the marker line and add everything after that to the list.

*EDIT* Your second problem happens because not all of the lines in the original file split to at least 3 fields. A blank line, for instance, results in an empty list so `e[1]` is invalid. I've updated the example with a nested iterator that filters out lines that are not the right size. You may want to do something different (maybe strip empty lines but otherwise assert that the remaining lines need to split to exactly 3 columns), but you get the idea

```
entries = []
for fn in filelist:
    with open('fn') as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if line.strip() == 'ID\tNAME\tGEO\tFEATURE':
                break
        #entries.extend(line.strip().split('\t') for line in fp)
        entries.extend(items for items in (line.strip().split('\t') for line in fp) if len(items) >= 3)
```

Comment: Thank you @tdelaney, I have now something like this: 

`filelist = fileinput.input()
entries = []

for fn in filelist:
    for line in fn:
        if line.strip() == "QLCID\tHEAD\tHEAD_DOCULECT\tTRANSLATION\tTRANSLATION_DOCULECT\tPOS":
            break
    entries.extend(line.strip().split("\t")for line in fn)`

But my index after parsing the entries is still "out of range"

Comment: @El_Patrón - how about posting that code as an edit to the question? And include the code where you get an "out of range" exception. The code shown doesn't index anything, so we need to see what happens next. You can add a quick note here so that I get a notification of a change.